# How to set the width of a textarea in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to set the width of a textarea to match the width of a particular image. Using `.width()` works for setting the width of an image, but not of a textarea.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var width = $("#my_image").width();
    $("#another_image").width(width); // works
    $("#my_textarea").width(width); // fails
});
```

How do I set the width of a textarea?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use jQuery's [`css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method like this:

`.css("width", width)`

or this, if you plan on setting more attributes:

`.css({"width":width})`

Answer (score 1):

You could try :

```
$("#my_textarea").css('width', width);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#my_textarea").css('width',width);
```

Also you might want to use [.outerWidth()](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/) to set `var width` depending on your padding/margin/border settings